# How to set the Radius Corners to View using DrawRect Method?

Tags: objective-c

using DrawRect method to draw a rectangle view. I have to set the radius corners of that particular rectangle view.I have written to draw a rectangle view below.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
int coordinate_x=60,coordinate_y=120,width=200,height=295;

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGRect drawTank = {coordinate_x, coordinate_y, width, height};

CGColorRef blackColor=[UIColor blackColor].CGColor;

CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0, 0, 255, 1);

CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0);

CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, blackColor);

CGContextStrokeRect(context, drawTank);
}
```

And i have to use fill the view and empty view use code below.

```
CGRect emptyTank = CGRectMake(coordinate_x, coordinate_y, width, height *(1-filledPercentage));

CGRect fullTank = CGRectMake(coordinate_x, coordinate_y+height *(1-filledPercentage),width, height * filledPercentage);
```

how to set the radius corner to the particular view. please help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply set the corner radius of a `UIView` with:

```
  view.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
```

If you are using beizer path , you can set corner radius with the following code:

```
UIBezierPath* rectanglePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: CGRectMake(55, 30, 133, 51) cornerRadius: 5];
[UIColor.grayColor setFill];
[rectanglePath fill];
```

within the drawRect method:

```
 - (void)drawRect: (CGRect)frame
{

    //// Rectangle Drawing
    UIBezierPath* rectanglePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 40, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 21, 133, 51) cornerRadius: 7];
    [UIColor.grayColor setFill];
    [rectanglePath fill];
}
```

Comment: Please send me the complete code to draw a view with radius corner.

Comment: my answer has the code,  and it has two ways to do it. Which one you prefer? Create a uiview programmatically ? or create it from sotryboard?